# JQuery TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Facing error on JSON.stringify(ApplObj) :
How to post this object to controller
JQuery Code -

```
    var ApplName = $("#ApplicantName").val();
    var ApplMobile = $("#ApplicantMobile").val();
    var ApplEmail = $("#ApplicantEmailId").val();
    var ApplFHName = $("#ApplicantFHName").val();

    var ApplObj = {
        ApplicantName: ApplName, ApplicantMobile: ApplMobile, ApplicantEmailId: ApplEmail, ApplFHName: ApplicantFHName
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("SaveApplicatDetail", "Dashboard")',
        data: JSON.stringify(ApplObj),
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

Controller Code... 
this jsonresult used for save records and return value...
this code is working in other project....

```
    public JsonResult SaveApplicatDetail()
    {
        try
        {
            var resolveRequest = HttpContext.Request;
            TicketMasterModel TMM = new TicketMasterModel();
            resolveRequest.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            string jsonString = new StreamReader(resolveRequest.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
            if (jsonString != null)
            {
                TMM = (TicketMasterModel)js.Deserialize(jsonString, typeof(TicketMasterModel));
            }
            int TicketId = 0;
            using (var db = new UnitOfWork())
            {
                DAL.tbl_TrnTicketMaster TM = new DAL.tbl_TrnTicketMaster();
                TM.ApplicantName = TMM.ApplicantName;
                TM.ApplicantMobile = TMM.ApplicantMobile;
                TM.ApplicantEmailId = TMM.ApplicantEmailId;
                TM.ApplicantFHName = TMM.ApplicantFHName;

                TM.FK_CompanyId = 1;
                TM.CustomerId = UserSession.UserId;
                TM.IsSubmissionLocked = false;
                TM.CreatedBy = UserSession.UserId;
                db.tbl_TrnTicketMaster.Insert(TM);

                TicketId = TM.PK_TicketId;
            }
            return Json(TicketId, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: where's your controller code? what's the type of parameter on action method?

Comment: you can always [edit] your question...

Comment: Have you tried this `JSON.stringify({ 'argument_name': ApplObj })`? Put name of the argument which you are using in controller.

Comment: i placed controller code no argument is used in controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Resolved - 
"JSON.stringify" is used array to convert it.

```
    var ApplName = $("#ApplicantName").val();
    var ApplMobile = $("#ApplicantMobile").val();
    var ApplEmail = $("#ApplicantEmailId").val();
    var ApplFHName = $("#ApplicantFHName").val();

    var ApplDetails = {
        ApplicantName: ApplName,
        ApplicantMobile: ApplMobile,
        ApplicantEmailId: ApplEmail,
        ApplicantFHName: ApplFHName
    }

    var ApplObj = { ApplicantDetail: ApplDetails };

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("SaveApplicatDetail", "Dashboard")',
        data: JSON.stringify(ApplDetails),
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

basically `JSON.stringify` turns a Javascript object into JSON text and stores that JSON text in a string.

try this,

```
        var ApplName = $("#ApplicantName").val();
        var ApplMobile = $("#ApplicantMobile").val();
        var ApplEmail = $("#ApplicantEmailId").val();
        var ApplFHName = $("#ApplicantFHName").val();

        var ApplObj = {
            'ApplicantName': ApplName, 'ApplicantMobile': ApplMobile, 'ApplicantEmailId': ApplEmail, 'ApplFHName': ApplicantFHName
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SaveApplicatDetail", "Dashboard")',
            data: JSON.stringify(ApplObj),
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I m facing error on JSON.stringify(ApplObj)....without JSON.Stringify passing ApplObj error "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" given

Comment: then put `JSON.stringify(ApplObj)` and try again. your problem in when create `ApplObj`

Comment: after using replacer same problem exist

Comment: try replacing this `data: JSON.stringify({ 'ApplObj ': ApplObj })`

Comment: did you replace `var ApplObj = {
            'ApplicantName': ApplName, 'ApplicantMobile': ApplMobile, 'ApplicantEmailId': ApplEmail, 'ApplFHName': ApplicantFHName
        }` like this ?

Comment: why you use `JSON.stringify(ApplObj)`. i think you want pass `ApplObj`. th`@Url.Action("SaveApplicatDetail", "Dashboard")` am i right ?

Comment: I am using this - var resolveRequest = HttpContext.Request;
            TicketMasterModel TMM = new TicketMasterModel();
            resolveRequest.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            string jsonString = new StreamReader(resolveRequest.InputStream).ReadToEnd();

Comment: instead of JSON.stringify(ApplObj)

Comment: try remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`